# How to classify agriculture employment data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, classification

I have employment data which are huge - about 500 data for each category, like agriculture field, fishing field etc. Now I want to categorise this data in to 7 ranges. Suppose <50=1, >50-100=2, etc. for producing an agriculture map of a country by showing these categories as a legend. I don't want to change my main GIS data. I only want to show this data into small categories in Map. How can I do it?

Comment: Are you interested in creating categorical data in a new field based on another field?  Perhaps with the field calculator?

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you want to do this in ArcMap.

Right click -> Properties -> Symbology 
You will need to select the `Classified` and finally classify in the way you want.

For more info check the [ESRI help file](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/About_symbolizing_layers_to_represent_quantity/00s500000034000000/)

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you might use grouping techniques in Layer Properties dialog box > Symbology tab > Categories. Here you would specify the classifications (0>50, 50>100 etc) and labels (1,2,3 etc). The legend in the layout view will use the labels you've specified, so you don't have to change anything in the underlying data.

[Organizing categories into groups](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Drawing_a_layer_using_categories/00s50000003m000000/)